# Can I replace a 20x2.25 tyre with a 20x1.75 tyre?

Tags: tire

My daughter's bike has a 20x2.25 tyre, but they are hard to come by here in NZ. More common is a 20x1.75 tyre. Will this fit? Looking at other posts, and some charts, I think it should work?

Comment: Probably will fit.  Depends on the width of the rim.

Comment: For what it's worth, I recently found a 20x2.25 at Basic Bikes in Christchurch.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus yes awesome! I didn't find that one while searching. Rim width is 20mm, so 1.75" should definitely fit, right?

Comment: @Boland I think I redirect someone to that answer about every couple of weeks

Comment: Any LBS in New Zealand should be able to order in 20x2.25  Many have them in stock.  Evo have one for $NZ30.  Can always order online and have it shipped.

Comment: Thanks @mattnz I used the wrong search terms indeed. I've found it at MyRide as well for $25 incl shipping :)